# Sales Order grid column name cached?

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid

**Magennto 1.9.4**

I added a column to the sales order grid like this:

```
$this->addColumn('data', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('X'),
        'index' => 'data', 
    ));
```

Afterwards I changed X to Y but the grid still shows X. I cleared the cache, nothing helps. Any idea how to update this?

Answer (score 0):

Please manually check your var/cache directory. If everything is still there, your site's cache has not been cleared. Please delete all directories in var/cache and try again